# TypeScript: Did you mean to call this expression?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component that requires a prop with `string` type. I also have a function that returns the `string`, it has the type `(value: any): string`.

When I am trying to pass it to my component `<Component stringProp={myFunction("value")} />` I get the error:

```
Type '(value: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How should I write the type for `myFunction` or to use the function in the prop? I don't want to call it outside of the component if possible.

Comment: i think you need to add more code for understand the problem Thx

Comment: You're passing a function, you should be passing a string. If you want to pass a function, change the interface. If you want to pass a string, execute the function rather than passing it.

Comment: @JMadelaine in JavaScript I could pass it as `() => myFunction()` and it would execute the function and use returned result as a value, but TypeScript complains on that format too

Comment: It doesn't execute the function. To execute the function you call it `myFunction()`. To pass it you pass the variable without parentheses `myFunction` or pass an anonymous function that calls your function `() => myFunction()`

Comment: @flppv hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @wentjun You suggest to modify the props of the component, I can't modify it, my question is if it's possible to use a function that returns a string in a prop, that has a requirement of the string type. The solution with running an anonymous function doesn't work as well, same error.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `interface` like so because in this way you can handle your prop and you can pass it a function or a string :

```
interface Props {
 YOUR_PROP_NAME : (value? : any) => string | string
};
```

and use it in your component

```
const App : React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {typeof props.YOUR_PROP_NAME  === "string" ? <div>{props.YOUR_PROP_NAME}</div> :  <div>{props.YOUR_PROP_NAME()}</div>}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

```
import React from "react";

export interface MyProps {
  some: string;
  another: number;
  oneMore: string;
}

const MyCom:React.FC<MyProps> = props =>{
...
};
```

Now you have all them props AND It includes children prop AND default Props as well

---

```js
import * as React from "react";

export interface MyProps {
  some: string;
  another: number;
  oneMore: string;
}

export function MyComponent (props: MyProps): React.ReactElement<MyProPs> {
  const { some, another, oneMore } = props;

  return (
     <p>{some}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your issue is as follows. You have specified that your component accepts a `string` as a prop, but you are passing it a function. You would need to updated the props interface to not expect a string, but rather a function which returns a string. It would look something like this.

```
interface Props {
    getString: (value: any) => string;
}
```

Now your component isn't expecting a string, but rather a function which matched the type you are passing in.